# Using dynamic variables in Windows batch

Tags: windows, variables, dynamic, batch-file

I have the following batch file:

```
set var1=LongOption1
set var2=Longoption2
set var3=LongOption3

if "%1" == "" (set activeVar=%var1%) else (

set activeVar=%1

)
```

My goal is to implement a dynamic variable, so I want to start my batch file with one argument. If I do not pass an argument to my batch file it shall set my activeVar to var1. But actually I would like to pass a variable that is taken as the active variable. To make it more clear:

I would like to have the opportunity to tell my batch file via an argument on the console which var it should take for further processing in later statements. 
So I could call my batch like this:

```
cmd --> ..../batch.bat var2
```

So I passed the String `var2` to my batch. Now, because the first argument is not empty, the batch should jump in the else path and set my `activeVar` to the value of `var2`. (I do not want to set `activeVar` to `"var2"`, I want it to be `"LongOption2"`)
Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas??? What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use delayed expansion here or a `call`.

```
set var1=LongOption1
set var2=Longoption2
set var3=LongOption3
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%1" == "" (
  set activeVar=%var1%
) else (
  set activeVar=!%1!
)
```

or using `CALL`

```
set var1=LongOption1
set var2=Longoption2
set var3=LongOption3

if "%1" == "" (
  set activeVar=%var1%
) else (
  CALL set activeVar=%%%1%%
)
```